# Looking for image similarity library that doesn't care about image dimensions

Tags: image, open-source

Does anyone know what open-source library Google uses for its Google Similar Image?

I need to find the similarity of two images of different sizes but slightly similar content. I need to get a metrics value.

Comment: What makes you think Google uses an open source library?

Comment: have tried perceptual diff and imagemagick. but both of it cant compare images that has different dimension.

Comment: Have you tried downscaling the larger image and then comparing?

Comment: yep. have tried using Imagemagick's Convert function, but the rescaling does not exactly produce a size that both images can agree with same dimension.

Comment: or is there any crop function ? means, I just cut the length of the longer part.

Comment: If you post an example of the images you are trying to compare, you might get a bit more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at SourceForge or Google Code?

[This project](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) looks very good. And the tag [ImageProcessing](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aImageProcessing) has 249 hits. Surely you will find something there.

Btw, do you have any requirements w.r.t. OS, programming language, etc?